# How to change data-videoid amp using jQuery

Tags: jquery, amp-html

How can I change the data-videoid youtube value using jQuery.

I currently have the following video id and code on every page, however, I'd like to be able to change the video as and when I need to on every page using jQuery .attr or .text (or whatever will work) but I can't seem to be able to find the right way to do this. My main problem is actually selecting data-videoid to manipulate the value.

```
<div class="youtube-wrap">    
<amp-youtube
data-videoid="08lxCVQMxxA"
layout="responsive"
width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>
```

So if I want to change 08lxCVQMxxA to Ea9NYoYxc5w for example, how?

I've tried the following

```
$( ".youtube-wrap.data-videoid" ).text("Ea9NYoYxc5w")
$( ".youtube-wrap" ).attr("src", "Ea9NYoYxc5w")
$( ".youtube-wrap.data-videoid" ).attr("src", "Ea9NYoYxc5w")
    $( "body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1220) > td.line-content > span.html-attribute-name" ).attr("src", "Ea9NYoYxc5w")
$( "amp-youtube.data-videoid" ).text("Ea9NYoYxc5w")
```

Comment: Did you get any result after trying the specified code snippet?

Comment: Literally nothing change on the page at all with any of these methods. I also tried changing other text on the page to make sure the script was hooked up and it changed it.

Comment: @user10400113 amp does not support jQuery

Comment: You can still use elements of amp with jquery and javascript. It just means the page won't be recognized as valid amp. My answer below works with amp and jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
$( "amp-youtube" ).attr('data-videoid','Ea9NYoYxc5w')
```

This works!

Comment: amp does not support jquery, so how can you do this.

Comment: It just means the markup is not valid, it still functions on the page. All I'm doing is pulling in external Javascript through amps cdn.

Answer (score 0):

First alert shows the current `VideoId` and second alert shows the new id after set it through the `Jquery`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
alert($('.youtube-wrap').find('amp-youtube').attr('data-videoid'));
$('.youtube-wrap').find('amp-youtube').attr('data-videoid','Ea9NYoYxc5w')
alert($('.youtube-wrap').find('amp-youtube').attr('data-videoid'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="youtube-wrap">    
<amp-youtube
data-videoid="08lxCVQMxxA"
layout="responsive"
width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>
```

Comment: what's about amp validation? Does amp support jquery ?